# NSSave panel default button size

Tags: macos, cocoa

How to increase the size of the default button of a NSOpenPanel?
A very rude approach i tried is t check the subviews of the openapanel & then get the reference of the default button from there. Can anyone suggest a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be impossible for a sandboxed app. From the docs:

> In a sandboxed environment, Open panels are drawn in a separate
>   process by the powerbox, not by AppKit itself. When the user chooses a
>   file to open, OS X adds that file to the app’s sandbox.

So you would have essentially no control over it.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/Classes/NSOpenPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html